# HTML5 solution for Streamtheworld.com streams

Tags: html, audio

There seem to be several inconclusive threads on if this is doable at all.

At the end of the day, I am in need of a mobile friendly, non-flash, (iphone compatible), player for streamtheworld streams.

Within the pls file, I have the following. I only need one to work. Has anyone been successful with this?

```
File1=http://3393.live.streamtheworld.com:80/WBAPAMAAC_SC
File2=http://3393.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/WBAPAMAAC_SC
File3=http://3393.live.streamtheworld.com:443/WBAPAMAAC_SC
File4=http://5843.live.streamtheworld.com:80/WBAPAMAAC_SC
File5=http://5843.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/WBAPAMAAC_SC
File6=http://5843.live.streamtheworld.com:443/WBAPAMAAC_SC
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that these URLs play through Soundmanager2 HTML5 mode on Safari in OSX when Quicktime is installed. Flash, Firefox, and Chrome however do not like them.